# With over a page of content the footer remains where the bottom of the screen was at top scroll

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, footer

I've been building an artist website to promote my music and I've ran into an obstacle with my footer. What I want is very simple (or so it would seem). I'm trying to create a footer that sits under the content/body and is at the very bottom of the site. No white space on the left, right, or bottom. Then when the site has minimal content the footer will sit at the bottom of the screen. The problem that I'm running into is that when the content is more than a page long, instead of pushing the footer down with it, the footer just sits where the bottom of the screen is (when scrolled to the top). This means that when the user scrolls to the bottom of the site, the footer remains in the middle somewhere, overlapping content.

I wish I had kept track of all the sites and forums I've been on and tried, but It's been several full days of searching. It's better than when it started (originally I couldn't push the left and right margins to full width), but this last problem is just evading me. Any help would be very much appreciated. (I am using a Wordpress Twenty-Twelve Child Theme if that helps)

[Undesired Footer](http://kjel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Undesired-Footer.jpeg)

[Desired Footer](http://kjel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Desired-Footer.jpeg)

My current hypotheses are as follows:

1. There is code somewhere that makes the footer stick to the bottom of the screen with minimal content, and it is constantly applied. From what I understand, the way people do this is by using min-height:100%, but with/without that line it makes no difference.
2. Maybe there is something not right in terms of my html hierarchy? Twenty-twelve used #masthead, #page, #main, and #colophon. I've come across a couple sites where people say to make sure the footer is outside of the main wrapper. I've done this but it hasn't worked.
3. Maybe the issue is not in footer at all? Maybe the other containers need to be changed. Maybe #main needs to be set to position:relative; or something (but that hasn't worked).

Here's all the html:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
<button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></button>
<a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
<?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>

</header><!-- #masthead -->

<div id="main" class="wrapper">

</div><!-- #page -->
</div><!-- #main .wrapper -->
<footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the footer css:

```
footer {
background:url(http://kjel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/footer-img.jpeg) repeat-x bottom center;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
bottom:0px;
min-width:100%; 
}
```

Also note that I have tried Ryan Fait's sticky footer which I've seen referenced quite a bit. I haven't been able to get it to work properly. I'm not a professional coder, I'm a musician with a basic knowledge of html and css trying to save cash. If I'm going about the footer the complete wrong way, feel free to set me straight. Any help is most appreciated! Oh and here's my site: www.kjel.ca

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wordpress theming, belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hey Raptor, thank for the tip. I wasn't sure if my problem had anything to do with my theme or if it was just a css/coding issue. I've added it to the wordpress forums. Should I delete it here?

Comment: Also here's the link to my website if you didn't notice it in the OP: [kjel.ca](http://kjel.ca)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#colophon {
    background:url(http://kjel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/footer-img.jpeg) repeat-x bottom center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    min-width:100%; 
}
```

instead of

```
footer {
    background:url(http://kjel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/footer-img.jpeg) repeat-x bottom center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    min-width:100%; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. Both #colophon and footer seem to do the exact same thing. I think it's because in html the footer is defined as footer id ="colophon" instead of div id="colophon", so either works.

Comment: *Hint*: in CSS, `0` has no unit, and the `footer` selector is fine.

Comment: @KjelSidloski Reason for my answer was, you have given property to the `footer` and if you notice there are 2 footer tag in your code.That's why it was displaying image 2 times.

Comment: @KjelSidloski One more thing, make sure you have closed all the tags, specially `</div>`.

Comment: @Raptor I've changed all the 0px; markings to 0; But it hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Good call #colophon does get rid of the duplicate footer. It doesn't solve the major problem of moving the footer underneath the content though. ALso, I've checked the tags, and unless I'm missing something, they seem to all be closed properly. <div id "page> comes on the second line, <div id "main"> comes right after </header> and they are both closed right before <footer id "colophon">

Comment: You moved on to different approach.So I am not able to see now ..But generally this kind of issue only come if you miss one of closing tag in your any file.Otherwise HTML reads content line by line and also align it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, I seem to have fixed the code. I cleaned up the code for #colophon. I changed it from this:

```
#colophon {
    background:url(http://kjel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/footer-img.jpeg) repeat-x bottom center;
    height:80%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    bottom:0;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:1%; 
}
```

To this:

```
#colophon {
    background: url("http://kjel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/footer-img-2.jpeg") repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 448px;
}
```

The value that seems to have been the source of the problem was bottom: 0; That put the footer below the content, but there was a right margin. To fix that I added this:

```
footer[role="contentinfo"] {
    line-height: 2;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

Thanks for your help guys.